# Getting 1004 error on code that worked after adding new code

Tags: excel, vba, byval

I'm stumped (doesn't take much). I have two bits of code that don't seem to work well together. I would like them to or find an alternative. The first is a command button code that clears contents and changes formatting. This worked perfectly fine until I added "if value changes" code. The value change code refers to cells in the range where the formatting is changing from the first code. I imagine this is the issue. The codes use named ranges for the most part. I have attempted to use cell addresses, defining range in code, protect/unprotect, and adding the sheet name to the range.

This code works just fine without the "if value changes" code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Sheets("PN Generation").unprotect Password:="1234"
    Range("SELECT").Value = 2
    Range("PNSELECT").ClearContents
    Range("SMC").ClearContents
    Range("ALL").Interior.ColorIndex = 35
    Range("ALL").Font.ColorIndex = 49
    Range("SMC").Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    Range("SMCD").Font.ColorIndex = 15
    Range("SMCD").Interior.ColorIndex = 15
    Call protect

End Sub
```

When using the below code, the above code returns an 1004 Application defined/Object defined error starting at line 5 - "Range("ALL").Interior.ColorIndex=35."

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D3")) Is Nothing Then
    
            If Range("PNI") = "G" Or Range("PNI") = "U" Or Range("PNI") = "L" Or Range("PNI") = "T" Then
            Sheets("Reverse Build").Range("MV").Copy
            Sheets("PN Generation").Range("PFLMV").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
        
        If Range("PNI") = "A" Or Range("PNI") = "B" Or Range("PNI") = "C" Or Range("PNI") = "V" Or Range("PNI") = "AR" Then
            Range("LV").Copy
            Range("PF").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
        
        If Range("PNI") = "S" Or Range("PNI") = "P" Then
            Range("SIN").Copy
            Range("PF").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
        
        If Range("PNI") = "F" Then
            Range("BARE").Copy
            Range("PF").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
        
        If Range("PNI") = "R" Then
            Range("LVU").Copy
            Range("PF").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
       End Sub
```

I'd like to understand why I'm getting the error and how to fix prevent the error.

Comment: Forgot to mention. the "ALL" named range is D2:F4 and D7:F7. D3 is the target cell.

Comment: You are only testing Range("PNI"), did you evaluate the possibility of using a `Select Case` block instead of the bunch of `If`s?

Comment: No, but only because I haven't had much luck in my efforts to use Select Case code. I understand the concept but I get caught up in the syntax. That's a good idea though. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: The good news is I was able to get Select Case to work. The bad news is it didn't stop the problem. I'm guessing the issue is when the Command Button code clears cells, it triggers the ByValue code before the Command Button code finishes.Does that make sense. Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: `Application.EnableEvents = False`... `Application.EnableEvents = True`?

Comment: Worked like a charm. I hate that I still don't think of these simple fixes. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Application.EnableEvents = False... Application.EnableEvents = True worked.

Thank you BigBen. You should know, you just helped a Bengals fan. lol